# Adjust Bootstrap 3 row size without less

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know how I can adjust the `.row` `width` of Bootstrap, that the `col grid` still work as used to, but just particular `.row`s are tighter as in default.

Thanks

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for reminding me, in 3.

Comment: @ShreyGupta sure, apologies for the delay. Worked fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adjust the row width, you can add the following statement in an internal style sheet: `.row {width:90%;}`, where you can replace 90% with any percentage value desired. This will still preserve the grid layout and responsive design while giving you control on the row widths.

Comment: thank you for this, but it will be not aligned in the middle anymore. Can I just use `margin: 0 auto;` or will this create any issues?

Comment: You should be able to use `margin:0 auto` or `text-align:center` on the `container` div, either should work.